Prove the following random variable is a.s. finite.
Question:Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent real random variables uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.
Define the record times of the sequence by $T_1=1$ and, for every $p\geq2$,$$T_p:=\inf\{n>T_{p-1}:X_n>X_{T_{p-1}}\}$$with the convention $\inf \emptyset:=\infty$.Show that $$\forall p\in \mathbb N,\mathbb{P}(T_p=\infty)=0$$Here is my attempt:
Since when $p=1$,it is true.I want to prove it by induction:Assume the case when $p=k-1$ is true,then$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T_p=\infty)=\mathbb P(T_p=\infty,T_{p-1}<\infty)+0\\=\sum_{m=p-1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(T_p=\infty,T_{p-1}=m)\\=\sum_{m=p-1}^{\infty}\mathbb P((\forall n\ge m, X_n\le X_m),T_{p-1}=m)
\end{align}$$I used the assumption in the first equality.However I am stuck here,because I don't know how to simplify the last equality.
Any help would be appreciated.

To show that $ \forall p \in \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{P}(T_p = \infty) = 0 $, we proceed as follows:
Step 1: Base Case ($p = 1$)
For $ p = 1 $, $ T_1 = 1 $ by definition. Since $ T_1 \neq \infty $, it is clear that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_1 = \infty) = 0.
$$
Step 2: Inductive Step
Assume that for some $ k \geq 1 $, we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_k = \infty) = 0.
$$
We aim to prove that $ \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty) = 0 $.
Step 3: Expression for $ \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty) $
By definition, $ T_{k+1} = \inf \{ n > T_k : X_n > X_{T_k} \} $. Using the inductive hypothesis:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty) = \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty, T_k < \infty).
$$
We can rewrite this using the law of total probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty) = \sum_{m=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty, T_k = m).
$$
Step 4: Conditioning on $ T_k = m $
For $ T_k = m $, we note that $ T_{k+1} = \infty $ implies $ X_n \leq X_m $ for all $ n \geq m $. Thus:
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty, T_k = m) = \mathbb{P}((\forall n \geq m, X_n \leq X_m), T_k = m).
$$
Using the independence of $ X_n $ and the fact that $ X_n $ are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, we observe that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\forall n \geq m, X_n \leq X_m) = 0,
$$
since $ X_n > X_m $ will almost surely occur for some $ n > m $ (the uniform distribution is continuous, and the probability of no larger value appearing in an infinite sequence is zero).
Alternatively, we can formalize this further by noting that the family of random variables $\{X_n - X_m\}_{n > m}$ is i.i.d., and let $p = \mathbb{P}(X_n - X_m \leq 0)$. Then:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\forall n > m, X_n \leq X_m) = \prod_{n > m} \mathbb{P}(X_n - X_m \leq 0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p^n = 0,
$$
since $p < 1$.
Step 5: Conclusion
Substituting back, we have:
$
\mathbb{P}(T_{k+1} = \infty) = \sum_{m=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}((\forall n \geq m, X_n \leq X_m), T_k = m) = 0.
$
Thus, by induction, $ \mathbb{P}(T_p = \infty) = 0 $ for all $ p \in \mathbb{N} $.
Summary
We have shown, via induction, that $ \forall p \in \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{P}(T_p = \infty) = 0 $.

Is this AI/GPT generated answer?

@dnqxt, no, it is not.
